# Spring Data how to implement not/not in/negate with org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher

Tags: jpa, spring-data

So, the question is a subject. I need to check user uniqueness when create/update. In case of an update, I need make **not** id, to be exclude the user from the result. Is there a way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh crap. It's not possible according to [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.html)